# Copying Vs Moving - Given code sample

Tags: c++11, c++98

I was going over some slides of Scott Meyers and it had the following code sample

```
typedef std::vector<T> TVec;
TVec createTVec();  // factory function
TVec vt;
… 
vt = createTVec();  // in C++98, copy return value to - vt, then destroy return value
```

I dont understand the following points and would appreciate it if someone could clarify this:

- Is createTVec an object on the stack of type TVec  ? If so what are
  () brackets next to it for ?

What does 
`vt = createTVec();` Was it suppose to be `vt = createTVec;` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a function, you have a declaration:

```
TVec createTVec();  // factory function
```

so it might look like:

```
TVec createTVec() {
   TVec ret;
   // initialize it
   return ret;
}
```

> What does vt = createTVec();

it assigns result from createTVec() function to vt variable.

In C++98 this function will return vector using temporary, since C++11 move semantics will be used. But, actually compiler might (and probably will) in such case do (N)RVO - Return Value Optimization.

Comment: so is `TVec createTVec(); ` a function prototype ?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Could you explain what you meant by `In C++98 this function will return vector using temporary`. I thought the copy constructor of the function createTVec would be called and a copy would be returned. Am i correct ? What did you mean by temporary. I am talking about C++98 right now. Suppose there is no optimization

Comment: Temporary is hidden TVec that is created from ret after return, and used to initialize vt. Actually temporary object will be created both for C++98 and C++11, but in C++11 move constructor will be invoked which can be very efficiently implemented.